# docker redis -Can't open the log file: No such file or directory

Tags: docker, redis, docker-compose

my OS is : ubuntu:15.10

And i want to use the **official docker-hub redis** , but met problems .

my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:

  redis:
    image: redis
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    volumes:
      -  ~/dbdata/redis_conf/redis.conf:/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
    volumes_from:
      -  redisdata
    environment:
      - REDIS_PASSWORD: 29c4181fb842b5f24a3103dbd2ba17accb1f7e3c8f19868955401ab921
    command: redis-server /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf

redisdata:
    image: redis
    volumes:
      - /home/keryhu/dbdata/redisdb:/data
    command: --break-redis
```

I copy the default redis.conf to the "~/dbdata/redis_conf/redis.conf" directory . And just modify the "requirepass" to "29c4181fb842b5f24a3103dbd2ba17accb1f7e3c8f19868955401ab921"

when i start the container ,i met an error -

```
*** FATAL CONFIG FILE ERROR ***
Reading the configuration file, at line 103
>>> 'logfile /var/log/redis/redis-server.log'
Can't open the log file: No such file or directory
```

Can help me ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As I can see [here](http://download.redis.io/redis-stable/redis.conf), the log file is not specified and all logs output to the stdout. I wouldn't change this behaviour because in that way docker will manage logs on his own which is standard and even more flexible way.

If you want to redirect logs output somewhere I would suggest using [`logging` directive](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#logging) of the composer.

Comment: my target is : add password env in the docker-compose.yml ,, do not care the log path . how resolve?

Comment: Open `~/dbdata/redis_conf/redis.conf`, find `logfile /var/log/redis/redis-server.log`, and replace it with `logfile ""`. That's it.

Comment: yes,i set log file "",  now i start it ok,but another issue -- i already set `requirepass  29c4181fb842b5f24a3103dbd2ba17accb1f7e3c8f198689821f7955401ab921` in local redis.conf  , and it exists in redis-container 's directory .. but  i  input `config get requirepass `    `it is ""`, why?

Comment: Where did you input this? I guess you have done it in redis-cli which is outside the container.

Comment: yes, first `docker exec -it redis bash` , then `redis-cli ` , i guess  i should  see the auth , because i have set it

Comment: Try to recreate containers with `docker-compose rm` and then `docker-compose up`. This should help.

Comment: I remove images and docker build  again . but ---`redisdata_1 | /entrypoint.sh: line 10: exec: --: invalid option
redisdata_1 | exec: usage: exec [-cl] [-a name] [command [arguments ...]] [redirection ...]
springredis_redisdata_1 exited with code 2
redis       | 1:C 12 Mar 13:31:10.806 # Warning: no config file specified, using the default config. In order to specify a config file use redis-server /path/to/redis.conf
redis       |                 _._      `  and not find requirepass

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106096/discussion-between-max-and-kery-hu).

Answer (score 0):

I happened to have encountered this problem too.Finally, i touched the redis.log on my host, then mount it on docker.

`step1: touch /yourself's location/redis-server.log
docker run -d -v /yourself's location/redis-server.log:/var/log/redis/redis-server.log -v /your/redis.config:/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf --name myredis redis redis-server /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf`

if you want to mount a file or dir,they must exist firstly,otherwise,it occours permission denied or empty dir.